# ant fresh_install build failed

Tags: ant, installation, dspace

I'm installing Dspace in Windows 7 and  I got it working fine with me until I got this error message:

[image]

I tried doing what the link :[build failed .. creation was not successful for an unknown reason](http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/build-failed-creation-was-not-successful-for-an-unknown-reason-td4664918.html) has said, but still nothing's change. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Where did you type "C:\Program Files\DSpace" ?
You might just need to remove the quotes there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check dspace.install.dir at build.properties, it seems to have a bad value.
Change the value to the location you want to install and use "/" character to the directory. For example C:/Program Files/Dspace.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I tried running the command on Ubuntu 22.04. The problem was I didn't have root privilege so I ran:

```bash
sudo ant fresh_install
```

Then it worked.